# MediaPlayer: audio file on /res/raw detected as an Integer

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I want to play an audio file when a Button clicked. But my code generate error code that says:

```
Cannot resolve method'create(context, int)'
```

So, my audio file is detected as an integer.

this is my fragment code:

```
package com.example.suha.belajarhurufhijaiyah;


import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class Hijaiyah extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton alif;
View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hijaiyah, container, false);
    alif = view.findViewById(R.id.alif_sound);

    alif.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.alif_sound:
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_alif);
            mp.start();
    }
}
}
```

That `R.raw.sound_alif` generate the error..

And it's my resource hier

[image: my resource hier]

Comment: All resources are integers! There is no problem with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to create MediaPlayer in **Fragment** use `getActivity()` or `getContext()` instead of `this` so use below code

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.alif_sound:
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound_alif);
            mp.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All resources are represented as `Integers` in the `R` class that is not your problem the problem is the `Context` your passing in a `Fragment` change `this` to `getActivity` So change your line to:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity, R.raw.sound_alif);
```